# Chinese version of the idiom "The word on the street"

Tags: idioms

"The word on the street" is an English idiom that basically means "rumors".

> The word on the street is that Bob's going to be fired.

I was wondering if there was a similar Chinese idiom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. "流言" (liú yán)

   > 一时间 **流言** 四起,亚洲陷入困境,资金加速流出,这些国家的本土银行纷纷倒闭。
   >
   > *Once the **rumor** got started that Asia was in trouble, these people started withdrawing their money faster and faster and it caused failures of domestic banks in these countries.*
2. "谣言" (yáo yán)

   > 布莱尔，如果你真的,编造了丹·汉弗瑞和那个老师的 **谣言** ，她可以告你诽谤。
   >
   > *Blair,if you started that **rumor** About Dan Humphrey and the teacher, She has a legitimate case for slander.*
3. "小道消息" (xiǎo dào xiāo xī)

   > 这些 **小道消息** 被当作一派胡言而一笑置之。
   >
   > *These **rumors** are regarded as nonsense and laugh at them.*

Comment: Hi there! Welcome!  Do you think you could expand on that answer a little?  When are those expressions used? How common are they?  Thanks!

Comment: example:"You need to part on good terms and you don't want your boss hearing rumors of your departure through the grapevine."

“你应该妥善告诉你的上司你离职这一事情，而不是让你的上司通过 流言 得知这一事实。”

Comment: "I think it would be better for both of us If we put those rumors to rest once and for all.
" “这对我们二者都好,让这些 谣言 永埋尘土。”

Comment: "So he starts spreading rumors that he is divine himself."
“于是他开始散播 谣言 ，说自己是神。”

Comment: @fanzhang - Can you please edit your question and add some easy to understand examples and some explanation in English.

Comment: +1 for the interesting examples! You could put those in your "answer" to make it more complete!

Answer (score 5):

literally, it is 街谈巷语. But nobody will speak this word any more, it is only used in the article.

When chinese people talk a rumor, they usually use 听说. This word means "I heard", especially for rumor.

Answer (score 4):

I guess 小道消息 or 坊间传闻 is closest. Others include 流言、流言蜚语、谣言。

Answer (score 1):

傳聞 is the word you are looking for! ;)

It is widely used in mass media, to regular chatting as well.

Answer (score 0):

I heard a different but similar phrase on a Chinese TV show.

It was: "你们听到什么风声？”

Pleco translates it into "the sough of the wind" or "rumour".

Sough apparently means "rustling" or "murmuring" in English.

Comment: "你们听到什么风声" is used among spies and detectives in war movies. 走漏风声 (a 成语) means leaking out information.

Answer (score 0):

The word on the street"： 东家长西家短.   rumors:"闲言碎语， 流言蜚语，街头传闻"